# MySql Data Range query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a fairly large MySql Innodb table with the following kind of stats,

```
Rows - 8277943+                     Server Ram - 128 Gb
Avg row Length - 575                Processor - Deca Core Intel
Data Size - 4.4 GB                  Overall Database Size -  500Gb
```

The problem is we have several queries on this table and they are running very slow now and am running out of ideas to optimize. For example some queries given below,

```
select  TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,w.msgCreatedOn,now()) as rnge
from t_xxx_dtls w 
where  w.profileId=17901
   and w.orgId=1448
   and w.actionStartDate BETWEEN '2016-07-27 05:08:00' and '2016-07-27 13:08:59'
   and w.currentlyActive=true and w.`action` not in (6,9,17)   
   and (
     w.parentId NOT in (
       select CASE WHEN d.parentId IS NOT NULL THEN d.parentId ELSE d.id END as ticketId
       from t_xxx_dtls d  where  d.profileId=17901 and d.orgId=1448 and d.actionStartDate     BETWEEN '2016-07-27 05:08:00' and '2016-07-27 13:08:59' and d.action in (2,4,7)
       group by ticketId
     )
     or ( w.parentId is null and w.inReplyId is null)
   )
   and w.msgId is not null
order by rnge desc
limit 0,1
```

Explain Plan [image: Explain Plan]

While we have simple queries like one below, which are beginning to get stuck,

```
select count(*)
from t_xxx_dtls d
where d.actionStartDate BETWEEN '2016-07-27 05:08:00' and '2016-07-27 13:08:59'
```

This according to the explain plan is checking a very large number of records, how can this be improved. I am reading about partition, but now sure if that can help.

Comment: Please show the table structure. Do you have an index on actionStartDate?

Comment: Please show mysql version, created indexes, oltp or olap database,...

Answer (score 0):

For the first query shown, I would think an index on (orgId, profileId, actionStartDate) *in that order* would be most helpful.

However, it would not help for the simpler second query; that one would benefit from an index starting with actionStartDate. The first query could benefit from such an index as well, but I am uncertain if MySQL would utilize the latter parts of a (actionStartDate, orgId, profileId) index when an `actionStartDate BETWEEN` condition is used.